# Twitter Button Stopped Showing Count 0

Tags: javascript, twitter, share

Ok so the official Twitter Share button has stopped display the counter if the count is 0. I've fixed this before with the Facebook share button (wants 3 shares before it shows the counter), but can't seem to fix it with the twitter button. Has anyone had any luck overriding this and forcing the counter to show at all times?

Answer (score 0):

See [Twitter Tweet Button does not count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805670/twitter-tweet-button-does-not-count)

Ran into same problem as you, but don't believe there's a real answer.

All I can do is rant and suspect this worked right once and then the failwhale told them that they need some caching implemented.

Which they did, with CDN replication that they don't have a clue about or worse yet can't control http expiration headers on. Or something.